# How to imitate finishAffinity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, affinity

The question is pretty self explanatory.

I'm doing a class that registers the activity of the user in order to avoid inactivity, after 2 minutes of no activity or everytime the user minimizes the app, the app should close. My code is the one listed below:

```
public class InActivityTimer extends Activity {

    public static final long DISCONNECT_TIMEOUT = 2*60*1000; // 2 min = 2 * 60 * 1000 ms
    public static int ESTADO_ACTIVIDAD=0; //Variable para saber si la actividad está al frente o no.

    private static Handler disconnectHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        }
    };

    private Runnable disconnectCallback = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Perform any required operation on disconnect
            //finish();
            finishAffinity();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),VentanaInactividadCierreAplicacion.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

            //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };

    public void resetDisconnectTimer(){
        disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
        disconnectHandler.postDelayed(disconnectCallback, DISCONNECT_TIMEOUT);
    }

    public void stopDisconnectTimer(){
        disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserInteraction(){
        resetDisconnectTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ESTADO_ACTIVIDAD ++;
        resetDisconnectTimer();
        comprobarEstado();
    }

    private void comprobarEstado() {

        if (ESTADO_ACTIVIDAD == 0){
//            Intent startMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashScreen.class);
//            startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
//            startActivity(startMain);
//            finish();
            finishAffinity();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RandomPassGEN cerrado por seguridad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        ESTADO_ACTIVIDAD--;
        stopDisconnectTimer();
        comprobarEstado();
    }

 /*   @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"La aplicación se reiniciará por seguridad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finishAffinity();
    }*/

}
```

As you can see, I'm using finishaffinty twice. How could I do it withous using that command? I'd like to avoid it because using finishAffinity() needs android +4.1

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You want to just remove all activities from the task? Are your activities running in another application's task?

Comment: No, they are not. @DavidWasser

Answer (score 1):

To close your application, do the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyRootActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("exit", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

`MyRootActivity` should be the root activity of your task (this is the one with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER in the manifest).

In `MyRootActivity.onCreate()` add the following after `super.onCreate()`:

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("exit")) {
    // User wants to exit, so do that
   finish();
   return;
}
... here is the rest of your onCreate() code
```

This will only work if `MyRootActivity` doesn't call `finish()` when it starts the next Activity in your workflow. If `MyRootActivity` does call `finish()` when it starts the next Activity, you should change it so that it doesn't. In that case you will need to handle the case where the user BACKs into `MyRootActivity` as a special case.

Comment: @user1269737 Why did you add this comment? This isn't necessary. I don't know why you think it is. Please create a new question if you are having specific issues. Your comment is confusing.

Comment: @user1269737 Not in this scenario. User's app is already running. This will not cause a "launch" `Intent` to be stored as the root of the task with the extra "exit" in it. That check is not necessary here. and it is confusing.